# Onde guardar credenciais de conexão à API no Android

Tags: android

Queria saber um lugar adequado para guardar a conexão com a api (link, usuário e senha), inicialmente estava pensando em guardar em um xml, mas acredito que qualquer usuário terá acesso a esse arquivo, podendo abrir e ler. Existe uma forma mais segura?

Comment: eu costumo fazer assim ó: crio uma class com um algoritimo de criptografia e criptografo o usuario e senha, depois, eu pego as strings geradas por esse algoritimo e seto elas como variaveis na class que vou usar, criptografadas mesmo como estão, e uso o algoritimo usado na geracao dessas variaveis para descriptografar elas e para abrir o meu db

Comment: dai, pode arrombar o codigo como quiser, que embora obfuscado, sei que dá pra reverter a engenharia, mas se nao abre o database, porque a class que gerou a criptografia é em separado, dai não pode fazer muito sem o db

Comment: Pode proteger o quanto for, engenharia reversa sempre trará as chaves privadas da API interna. Todos os aplicativos, como Facebook, Instagram, Snapchat já possuem API Internas expostas na internet. Qualquer `apktool` revelará o seu código, incluindo as chaves. A maior parte dos aplicativos usam HMAC para autenticar e é baseado no User-Agent, nele é informado também a versão do aplicativo usado, *isso influencia o retorno também*. O Snap usa AES (não me lembro qual), com uns padding um tanto quanto estranhos.  Além disso um VPN/Network Monitor é fácil descobrir o que está enviando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***"A melhor maneira de proteger segredos é não colocá-los no código."***

Não sendo possível, estas são algumas das opções onde os guardar:

- Em *string resources*.
- Escondidos no código fonte.
- Escondidos em *BuildConfigs*.
- Usando Proguard.
- Strings encriptados/mascarados.
- Escondidos em classes criadas usando o NDK.

Qualquer que seja a opção escolhida, ela não garante, a 100%, a protecção dos valores guardados, apenas dificulta a sua obtenção.
Um utilizador que consiga "quebrar" uma, "quebra" as outras. É uma questão de ter mais ou menos trabalho.

Assim sendo, escolha a mais fácil de implementar, use *strings* declarados no arquivo *res/values/strings.xml*.

```
<resources>
    <string name="user">myEmail@gmail.com</string>
    <string name="password">dfr125NF56</string>
</resources>
```

Referências:

- [Hiding Secrets in Android Apps.](https://rammic.github.io/2015/07/28/hiding-secrets-in-android-apps/)

<sub>Nota: Para ter acesso ao código da aplicação, caso a aplicação seja distribuída na Google Play, é necessário ter um dispositivo "rooteado". Isto retira à maioria dos utilizadores a possibilidade de acederem aos "segredos" guardados na aplicação</sub>