# Como acessar outro aplicativo com banco de dados SQLCipher, passando a senha no Content Provider?

Tags: android, android-content-provider

No código abaixo, eu concedo acesso ao banco de dados no app1, utilizando Content Provider, que faz uso do SQLCipher:

**App1**

```
public class StudentsProvider extends ContentProvider {

private SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    Context context = getContext();
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase("password");
    return db != null;
}
```

No app2, eu faço a query no banco de dados do app1:

**App2**

```
static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.example.a436236692.myapplication.StudentsProvider";
static final String URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/students";
static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(URL);
private void carregaResultados() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor c = cr.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        //reading db...
    }
}
```

Mas eu quero passar a senha pelo Content Provider, do app2 para o app1 e mudar esse *hardcode*:

> db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase("password");

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Que eu saiba isso não é possível.

O que deve fazer é definir permissões que as aplicações que queiram aceder ao provedor devem ter.

No AndroidManifest da aplicação do provedor declare um ou mais elementos `<permission>`:

```
...
<permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.DEADLY_ACTIVITY"
    android:label="@string/permlab_deadlyActivity"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_deadlyActivity"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.COST_MONEY"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
...
```

Aplicações que desejarem usar o provedor terão de declarar no seu AndroidManifest os respectivos `<uses-permission>`.

Referências:

- [Permissões do provedor de conteúdo.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#Permissions)
- [Definir e impor permissões.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#defining)

Comment: Eu já imaginava que não pelo content provider, tentei manipular o URI passando o dado por ele, mas não funciona. Referente as permissões, estão tudo de acordo. O problema é que ao acessar o DB com SQLCipher, apenas com o contexto da app2, o app1 retorna nulo. Eu lí sobre utilizar o sharedpreferences e passando usuário e senha, só não sei o quanto isso é seguro. Se puder me dar uma luz do que eu possa implementar, ficarei muito grato. Obrigado de qualquer forma. =)

Comment: Também tinha pensado no URI mas não vi como. Não entendi o que quer dizer com "o app1 retorna nulo".

Comment: Quis dizer que sem senha, o retorno da resposta do app1 é nulo. Como tabela não retornou o objeto, aí a aplicação "quebra", por causa do null pointer.

Comment: Mesmo usando `db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase("password");`?

Comment: Desta forma funciona! Sem senha que dá erro...

Comment: Então qual é o problema? Se é ter a *password* no código, na minha opinião, não é problema. No entanto veja [Onde guardar credenciais de conexão à API no Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194393/2541).