# Construção de uma string em tempo real

Tags: android

Na construção de um app me foi sugerido não incorporar a chave pública a nenhum código como uma string literal. Embora a mesma não seja secreta, ela pode vir ser substituída por uma outra numa possível tentativa de fraude. Como solução foi indicado construir a string em tempo real do zero ou usar manipulação de bit (por exemplo, XOR com alguma outra string) a fim de esconder a chave real.

Como isso funciona?

Comment: Relacionado:[Onde guardar credenciais de conexão à API no Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194393/2541)